# Juno Pointer size small on HIDPI screen

Tags: desktop

I have a Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro. I just installed Juno,and everything great so far. Only thing i am noticing is that the cursor is not scaling properly. It is difficult to describe when  is the issues happening, as it is really very random. For instance, in desktop apps it shows up very small (when I select something, it shows a normal sized cursor). On websites, from Epiphany, the cursor is small, but whenever i hover over any link, again, it shows a regular sized pointer. This is very annoying really. I have followed instructions on forums, such as using dconf to fix the cursor size, but sadly had no luck. Also tried elementary-tweaks, but the issue seems to stick around. Any help on this would be really appreciated.